# C# changes a "properly formated"(?) url into a virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to C# so I may not be asking this correctly.  I'm trying to redirect to a different url based upon the query string.

On my page http://admin.hcc.musc.edu/default.aspx  I have added:

```
<script runat="server">
          protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
          {  
          // take the value of the memberid
          string memberidvar = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["MemberID"];

         // in case of the 117 member ID then do nothing just exit the function or redirect to 
          //   the main website 
          if(memberidvar == "117")
          {
          // return; // if we want to exit the code 

         // if we want to redirect to the main website; 
        Response.Redirect("https://researchers.hcc.musc.edu", true);
       }

       try
        {
         Response.Redirect("https://researchers.hcc.musc.edu?MemberID=" + 
         Convert.ToString(memberidvar), true);
        }
       catch
        {
       // redirect to made error page or write line with error
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Direct");
         }
      }
</script>
```

And everything work find for any number other than 117

If I go directly to the url manually it works fine.  I've check the IIS 6.1 and there are no redirects or other issues besides being 6.1

The error I get with 117 is

```
    [HttpException (0x80004005): 'https:/researchers.hcc.musc.edu/' is not a valid virtual 
     path.]
     System.Web.Util.UrlPath.CheckValidVirtualPath(String path) +11924876
     System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Combine(String appPath, String basepath, String relative) +141
     System.Web.VirtualPath.Combine(VirtualPath relativePath) +159
     System.Web.HttpContext.RewritePath(String path, Boolean rebaseClientPath) +160
     System.Web.UrlMappingsModule.UrlMappingRewritePath(HttpContext context) +180
     System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
     +139
     System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
     System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& 
     completedSynchronously) +88
```

And you can see that there is only one slash after https. Is there a special encoding that I should use?  Why only 117 and not 124?

Comment: Are you sure your code doesn't have the typo of a single slash in that URL?  The rest of the URL in the error is certainly different from the URL in the code shown, which implies that either some changes were made when posting the question or that this isn't the code causing the problem...

Comment: I put the original xxx's in the url to hide the real site- but I changed it back to the real cut and paste code.  Thanks for the question

Comment: move the code from the markup to the code behind page load event. I think some of the spacing or the "//" are not being seen though correctly. Just another REALLY good reason to move out the code from the markup....